# django css: general query on CDNs and crispy forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-crispy-forms

I have set up a page and have implemented bootstrap using the CDN code that is recommended to access the online bootstrap server:

for the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However eventually my site will have to go live and I'm not certain that this code will suffice when that happens and I feel I should download the actual bootstrap code.

Furthermore if I download the bootstrap code properly and put it in a hypothetical media folder called "css2" such that it won't interfere with my own custom css files, where do I then put crispy_forms.

As of now I am holding them in the downloaded crispy forms files within "media"- on the same level as "myproject" but the "{ load crispy_forms}" tag doesn't look in the media folder because the "CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'" does not specify a path to look for the crispy forms content... the crispy forms website tells to look up the django documentation for how to organise my media folder but searching the website under "cripy forms" returns nothing.....

Finally, I have added crispy forms to my installed apps:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'myproject.myapp'
'crispy_forms',   ###Registered
 )
```

However when i migrate and run the server I get an error:

```
 ImportError: No module named myappcrispy_forms
```

so I rearranged the order of the modules and then got this error:

```
 ImportError: No module named crispy_forms
```

1. Should i download bootstrap properly or do the CDNs suffice?
2. Where do I store the bootstrap code and how will it affect my own CSS code?
3. How do register the module crispy_forms? and where do I store the crispy forms folder there is little documentation on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using CDN has it's pros and cons: it allows you to cache bootstrap files, so that your site pages should be downloaded faster from the second time. On the other hand, you do not usually need to use all the bootstrap css functionality, but only a tiny bit of it. In that case local and "self-cleaned" bootstrap files are prefered. Project collectors like Gulp can really help you with the "cleaning" of bootstrap css.
2. I usually store bootstrap files in `/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`
   and `/static/js/bootstrap.js` - in the same folder with other css and js files. In order to give your own css more priority just link it in html file after bootstrap files.
3. Well, personally I think `crispy_forms` have quite clear [documentation.](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) To start using it you should only: install it, add app to Installed apps in `settings.py` and point to the css framework you  want to use by setting a template pack variable. From docs you can see that crispy no longer upload it's own bootstrap files. It will use yours instead.